# Is it a bad idea to define class variables in a header file?

Tags: c++, oop

```
// myHeader.hpp

class Foo {

public:
    Foo(SomeClassPtr *ptr, std::string text);
    Foo(std::string text);
    Foo();
    // some code where it is checked that scPtr is not a nullptr
    ~Foo();
private:
    SomeClassPtr *scPtr=nullptr;
    
    // some other members

}
```

I don't want to write `scPtr=nullptr` in the 2 Foo constructors that don't have the `SomeClassPtr` as an argument I just made the `scPtr` a `nullptr` by default.
Now I want to know if this is a bad idea or if this ok to do i.e to define
class variables in a header file.

Comment: It's a good idea. Not wanting to repeat it in every constructor is reasonable.

Comment: really good to know thanks

Comment: Not only is it okay, it's largely considered a good guideline to follow https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c48-prefer-in-class-initializers-to-member-initializers-in-constructors-for-constant-initializers

Comment: The SomeClassPtr * gives indication that you want to use raw pointers of ptrs ... unusual. Also your Foo has its rule of three violated so won't pass any review.